# How to show different date pickers on iOS and Android (native ones) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

I would like to show the native date picker depending on the device. For example UIDatePicker if it's iOS.

I've tried to add SelectDateTextField inside my widget and it works, but it looks like the Android one. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the Platform then need to write specific widgets as per your need.

Use the APIs provided by the Dart.

Example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```

Your Widget

```dart
Platform.isIOS ? CupertinoWidget() : MaterialWidget()
```